# Which File Is The Executable

Tags: shortcuts, ubuntu-15.04

Newbie to Ubuntu here, running LTS 15.04 and I installed `brackets`  I know I can go to Search your computer and find the (windows term) exe that way, but I want to place a shortcut on my desktop to launch this file.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Open Nautilus

If you have not installed it,

```
 sudo apt-get install Nautilus
```

2) Navigate to /usr/share/applications

3) Right-click on the application you want to use and select copy

4) Click on your desktop and select paste

4) Right click on the icon that has just been created and select properties
    On the Permissions tab check Execute then click Close.

for more information you can [use this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450266/an-easy-way-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut) thread.

Comment: locking it to the launcher ads it to the launcher on the left side of the screen.  I need it to be on the desktop.

Comment: try this improved answer.